# How to does constructors in provider works?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

```dart
class Brain with ChangeNotifier {
  List<List<IconData>> icon = [];

  Brain() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      List<IconData> temp = [];
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        temp.add(Icons.square_outlined);
      }
      icon.add(temp);
    }
    [...]
  }
}
```

After some testing it seems like provider is calling it's constructor every widget state, but my icon list doesn't reset after changing some of the icons. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to use `notifyListeners();` when you need to refresh your Ui, use it at the end of your `Brain` constructor after your process finished and see the result

```
Brain() {
    ...
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Its better to use a function outside the constructor and use that, the constructor will create once when you provide the provider,